# I am getting garbage value while using operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have got a question -

> Write a c++ program to calculate Gross salary(net salary+DA+TDS) for 4 employees where overload the + operator for getting the total salary obtained by all the 4 employees. Also get the average salary of employees by operator overloading. display all the details of all four employees. Also display who is getting highest salary. Employee salary must be entered by the user at runtime.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Employee
{
    private:
        int net_salary, DA, TDA, Gross_salary;
    public:
        void SetData(int net, int da, int tda, int gross)
        {
            net_salary=net;
            DA=da;
            TDA=tda;
            Gross_salary=gross;
        }
        void GetData()
        {
            cout << "Enter net salary: "<<net_salary;
            DA = (15*net_salary)/100; //Declaring the value of DA as 15% and calculating the amount 
            //on basis of net salary of the employee
            TDA = (10*net_salary)/100; //Declaring the value of TDA as 10% and calculating the amount
            // of TDA on basis of net salary
            Gross_salary = net_salary+DA+TDA;
        }
        void DisplayData()
        {
            cout << "Total Gross Salary = "<<Gross_salary;
        }
        Employee operator +(Employee e)
        {
            Employee temp;
            temp.Gross_salary=Gross_salary+e.Gross_salary;
            return temp;
            }
};
int main()
{
    Employee e1,e2,e3,e4,e5;
    e1.GetData();
    e2.GetData();
    e3.GetData();
    e4.GetData();
    e5=e1+e2+e3+e4;
    e5.DisplayData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not callingn`SetData()` anywhere, so your data members have no values assigned to them when `operator+` tries to use them.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble comes from the absent initial values for the data members.

```
// ...
cout << "Enter net salary: " << net_salary;
DA = (15*net_salary)/100;
// ...
```

Here, in the `GetData()` member function, that is called after you have created five default  initialized objects `e1,e2,e3,e4,e5` of `Employee` type. The `net_salary` here is of built-in type and is default initialized by the [implicitly defined default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-defined_default_constructor), hence it has an **undefined value**. Then you assign this undefined value to the `DA` and so on in the body of the `GetData()`.

You should not look toward the `SetData()` as a solution for this, since it should act as a *setter* method, a method used to modify an **already initialized object**. You will need to implement constructor(s) for your class, or you can at least supply in-class initializers for the members, like so:

```
// ...
int net_salary=0, DA=0, TDA=0, Gross_salary=0;
// ...
```

---

I can't help but notice that `GetData()` either has a confusing name or tries to do more than it is intended to do. It does some internal computation, which is ok for a *GetSomething* function, but it modifies internal data while does some prints.

Also, note the line (in the `GetData()`):

```
Enter net salary:
```

Will be followed by an **output**, you won't be given a chance to input any data in the `GetData()`. I assume, you may want to create **a constructor that takes input from a user**, and then call a function to do all the needed computations.

Comment: I initialized the values as u suggested but still not getting the desired output

Comment: @Vica what do you expect as an output?

Comment: I have to take net salary from 4 values then calculate gross value and print sum of gross salary of those 4 employee

Comment: @Vica then you have to supply needed values for objects, which is about constructors.

Comment: I didn't understand what r u saying ?

Comment: @Vica I advise to get familiar with the following: [Constructors in C++](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/constructors/).

Comment: @Vica the bottom line: your `e1,e2,e3,e4,e5` all have data members with undefined values and the `GetData()` does not populate these objects with any meaningful data as well.